# Page not found (404) error on company code that I just cloned and should work. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Tags: python, django, url, localhost

A coworker and I are getting the same issue when we clone the Central Desk website from our repository. It is giving us the Page not found (404) error and we don't know why. The code should work fine, considering its the code for our website.

I've tried it connected to our VPN and unconnected, I've restarted the clone process and redone everything and I still get the error. I've tried making Redis in protected mode and out and nothing work. I've looked at our urls.py file and the settings_development.py file and they both look okay.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout_then_login

from heart.views import DashBoard, get_names
from heart.forms import LoginForm
from heart.login import login_set_desk
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns =[
        # Examples:
        # url(r'^apps/central_desk/$', 'centraldesk.views.home', name='home'),
        # url(r'^apps/central_desk/centraldesk/', include('centraldesk.foo.urls')),

        # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
        # url(r'^apps/central_desk/admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

        # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
        url(r'^apps/centraldesk/helm/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^apps/centraldesk/heart/', include('heart.urls')),
        url(r'^apps/centraldesk/items/', include('item_tracker.urls')),
        url(r'^apps/centraldesk/lost_and_found/', include('lost_and_found.urls')),
        url(r'^apps/centraldesk/mail/', include('mail.urls')),
        url(r'^apps/centraldesk/login/$', login_set_desk, name="login"),
        url(r'^apps/centraldesk/dashboard/$', DashBoard.as_view(), name="dashboard"),
        url(r'^apps/centraldesk/logout/$', logout_then_login, name="logout"),
        url(r'^apps/centraldesk/forum/', include('forums.urls', namespace='forums')),
        url(r'^apps/centraldesk/comm/', include('comm_log.urls')),
        url(r'^apps/centraldesk/checkin/', include('checkin.urls')),
        url(r'^apps/centraldesk/residents/', get_names ),
        url(r'^apps/centraldesk/$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('dashboard'), permanent=True)),
        url(r'^apps/centraldesk/cash_drawer/', include('cash_drawer.urls')),
        url(r'^apps/centraldesk/reports/', include('reports.urls')),
        url(r'^apps/centraldesk/feedback/', include('feedback.urls')),

]
```

---

```
from .settings_general import *

# debug value is referenced in mail/models.py to determine whether the mailer send function is called.
DEBUG = True

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'techops.django_auth.backends.ActiveDirectoryBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

"""Emails are sent with mail creation. It's found in mail/models.py."""
SEND_EMAILS = False

REDIS_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
REDIS_NAMES_DB = 9

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE'  : 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME'    : 'vagrant',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER'    : 'vagrant',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'vagrant',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST'    : '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT'    : '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media'))

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../static/'))
```

Above is first the urls.py file and second is the settings_development.py file. We just want to be able to get to the expected page.

Comment: Tell us the URL you're trying to access, and show us the Django error page.

Comment: @JohnGordon I was just trying to access the local host at 127.0.0.1:8000 and it was just the 404 error with it telling me where it explored to try and find the page. I ended up figuring it though, so thank you so much for your fast response! I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind! For those who would like to know, to edit on the local host we have an app for Central Desk on the host so the URL for that was:
127.0.0.1:8000/apps/centraldesk

At least that's my best shot at guessing as to why we have to go to that URL.